# Rails 3.1 App just visible on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedora, ports

I've made a Rails 3.1 App and deployed it in production-mode on a local fedora 16 server.
On the server I can access the Application successfully.

Now when I'm trying to access the application from another machine in the local network it fails.

Webrick says on startup

```
Rails 3.1.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Pinging this machine works.

I also edited `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` adding

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

and restarted iptables without any success.

Is there something I missed?

Comment: what url are you trying to access from remote machine

Comment: The server is 192.168.0.133 and I try http://192.168.0.133:3000

Comment: try running it on port 80
you will need to be root to do so..
$rails s -p 80

Comment: @PriteshJ That doesn't help him. What if he wants to run another app as well?

Comment: @cris Ledet,Yes, I agree

Answer (score 0):

What web server are you using?
With apache you need to make sure you're 'listening' to the URL and ports. This is set up in config files. Local host is set up by default, so if you havent set it up for either a URL or IP then you need to do so.

/etc/hosts.allow

```
  #
  # /etc/hosts.allow
  #
  sshd: ALL: ALLOW
  httpd: ALL: ALLOW
  ruby: ALL: ALLOW
  WEBrick: ALL: ALLOW
  webrick: ALL: ALLOW
  # End of file
```

Comment: I'm using the build in WEBrick 1.3.1 on the default port 3000, I'm not using apache. Starting WEBrick with the binding on 192.168.0.133 doesn't work either.

Comment: /etc/hosts.allow is empty. Do you know what to do to configure it?

Answer (score -1):

try running it on port 80

```
$ rails s -p 80
```